# How to edit a plist programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

I have a code to edit a plist file. But when the code runs, it changes the plist file but it deletes some other dictionaries. You can look at the images to see what I mean.

To see the edited word, look at dictionary "item 1" and at string "name". You will see that it needs to change from "Second" to "newVALUE".

The ***original plist*** is the image of the plist when the plist was created.
Then you have the ***expected plist*** which is what the plist should look like. And the ***edited plist*** is the plist after the code was applied.

**This is the code:**

```
NSString *plistPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
plistPath = [plistPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PassaveData.plist"];

NSMutableArray*  newContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *Dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[newContent objectAtIndex:1]];
[Dict setValue:@"newVALUE" forKey:@"name"];
[Dict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

**These are the images**

[Click to see the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCugJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original plist contains an array of dictionaries. You create a new dictionary and then overwrite the original array-based plist with just the one new dictionary.

You need to update loaded array with the updated dictionary and then write out the whole updated array.

```
NSMutableArray *newContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [newContent[1] mutableCopy];
dict[@"name"] = @"newVALUE";
newContent[1] = dict;
[newContent writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Note the use of modern syntax for the array and dictionary.

Comment: I think its update data only in document Directory not in original .piist file.

Comment: suppose I want to change app name after first build how can I change? I have already Try                                                                             [plistDict setValue:@"com.xyz.Getdata" forKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
[plistDict setValue:@"Getdata" forKey:@"CFBundleName"];
[plistDict setValue:@"MyProject" forKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];

Comment: @BhumeshPurohit You can't update any file in the app's resource bundle. It's read-only.